# Please explain this abbreviated ES6 JSX declaration

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, survivejs

An example in the [SurviveJS](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack_and_react/) handbook in the chapter on React and Webpack has me confused.

In `Note.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>Learn Webpack</div>;
```

This deviates in a number of ways from what appears to be the standard way of declaring React components using JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
class Note extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Learn Webpack</div>;
  }
}
```

How does the first example work?

1. How does it know the component is called `Note` so that it can be referred to as `<Note/>` in some parent component? Simply by filename match (removing the `.jsx` part?)
2. Where's the `render()` function? And how is it possible to omit it?
3. What are the limitations of this approach? I am guessing that it only works for wrapping a very simple rendered output, just mapping properties into some HTML...
4. Where is this style documented? I can't seem to find any [official](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It doesn't, when you do `<Note />` that is just looking for a variable named `Note` in the local scope. When the component is imported into another file, you can name it whatever you want. e.g. `import Note from './Note';` would import the default-exported function in your example.
2. This is a stateless function component, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions, as you linked to yourself. The function itself is the `render`, it has no class instance.
3. They can store no state since they just take inputs and render outputs.
4. Your specific example is just an arrow function. The documentation linked above uses standard non-arrow functions, but they are essentially interchangable in this case. e.g.

   ```
   export default () => <div>Learn Webpack</div>;
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   export default function(){
     return <div>Learn Webpack</div>;
   }
   ```

Comment: Worth noting that `import Note from "note"` will assign the `export default` value (the stateless function component) to the variable `Note`, if one is not yet used to ES6 modules.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One thing that is still not clear to me is how we were allowed to skip the `render()` method definition. Is there some magic that's happening in the transpiler when the JSX is converted to JS and the ES6 is converted down?

Comment: All you are doing when you do `<Note />` is passing React a function. React decides what to do with it. If you pass it a constructor function, it'll treat it like a component and create an instance and everything, if you pass it a function that returns JSX, it will basically automatically wrap that function in a component that calls the function on render.